# How can I get the transpiled code from the monaco editor?

Tags: typescript, monaco-editor

How can I get the transpiled TypeScript code from the monaco editor? Also, is it possible to access the TypeScript language service? I tried this:

```
monaco.languages.typescript.getTypeScriptWorker();
```

But it returns `Promise<any>` and I have no idea what to do with that!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After much research it appears the TypeScript `LanguageService` interface is partially exposed via a worker proxy object.  This may be because the service is in another thread and messages are pushed to it, thus the need for using promises.

To make things easier I reviewed the exposed functions on the returned object and created this definition; hope it helps someone:

```
namespace ts {
    export interface IMonacoTypeScriptServiceProxy {
        _getModel(uri: string): Promise<{ _eol: string, _lineStarts: any, _Lines: string[], length: number, _uri: Uri, _versionId: number }>;
        findRenameLocations(uri: string, position: number, findInStrings: boolean, findInComments: boolean, providePrefixAndSuffixTextForRename?: boolean): Promise<readonly RenameLocation[] | undefined>;
        getCodeFixesAtPosition(uri: string, start: number, end: number, errorCodes: readonly number[], formatOptions: FormatCodeSettings, preferences: UserPreferences): Promise<readonly CodeFixAction[]>;
        getCompilationSettings(): Promise<CompilerOptions>;
        getCompilerOptionsDiagnostics(): Promise<Diagnostic[]>;
        getCompletionEntryDetails(uri: string, position: number, name: string, formatOptions: FormatCodeOptions | FormatCodeSettings | undefined, source: string | undefined, preferences: UserPreferences | undefined): Promise<CompletionEntryDetails | undefined>;
        getCompletionsAtPosition(uri: string, position: number, options: GetCompletionsAtPositionOptions | undefined): Promise<WithMetadata<CompletionInfo> | undefined>;
        getCurrentDirectory(): Promise<string>;
        getDefaultLibFileName(options: CompilerOptions): Promise<string>;
        getDefinitionAtPosition(uri: string, position: number): Promise<ReadonlyArray<DefinitionInfo> | undefined>;
        getEmitOutput(uri: string, emitOnlyDtsFiles?: boolean): Promise<EmitOutput>;
        getFormattingEditsAfterKeystroke(uri: string, position: number, key: string, options: FormatCodeOptions | FormatCodeSettings): Promise<TextChange[]>;
        getFormattingEditsForDocument(uri: string, options: FormatCodeOptions | FormatCodeSettings): Promise<TextChange[]>;
        getFormattingEditsForRange(uri: string, start: number, end: number, options: FormatCodeOptions | FormatCodeSettings): Promise<TextChange[]>;
        getNavigationBarItems(uri: string): Promise<NavigationBarItem[]>;
        getOccurrencesAtPosition(uri: string, position: number): Promise<ReadonlyArray<ReferenceEntry> | undefined>;
        getQuickInfoAtPosition(uri: string, position: number): Promise<QuickInfo | undefined>;
        getReferencesAtPosition(uri: string, position: number): Promise<ReferenceEntry[] | undefined>;
        getRenameInfo(uri: string, position: number, options?: RenameInfoOptions): Promise<RenameInfo>;
        getScriptFileNames(): Promise<string[]>;
        getScriptKind(uri: string): Promise<ScriptKind>;
        getScriptSnapshot(uri: string): Promise<IScriptSnapshot | undefined>;
        getScriptVersion(uri: string): Promise<string>;
        getSemanticDiagnostics(uri: string): Promise<Diagnostic[]>;
        getSignatureHelpItems(uri: string, position: number, options: SignatureHelpItemsOptions | undefined): Promise<SignatureHelpItems | undefined>;
        getSuggestionDiagnostics(uri: string): Promise<DiagnosticWithLocation[]>;
        getSyntacticDiagnostics(uri: string): Promise<DiagnosticWithLocation[]>;
        isDefaultLibFileName(uri: string): Promise<boolean>;
    }
}
```

It is used like this:

```
var editor = monaco.editor.create(...etc...);
var tsProxy: ts.IMonacoTypeScriptServiceProxy;

monaco.languages.typescript.getTypeScriptWorker()
            .then(function(worker: (v: monaco.Uri) => Promise<ts.IMonacoTypeScriptServiceProxy>) {
                worker(editor.getModel().uri)
                      .then(function(proxy) {
                            tsProxy = proxy;
                      });
            });
```

Now the proxy function is called `getEmitOutput(uri: string, emitOnlyDtsFiles?: boolean)`.  The `uri` is the filename, which is a `monaco.Uri` converted to a string (a `model` in monaco terms is a single file in the editor), so:

```
tsProxy.getEmitOutput(editor.getModel().uri.toString())
                                    .then((r) => { console.log(r.outputFiles[0].text); });
```

Returns the transpiled JavaScript, AND all other files as well (if available)! You're welcome. :)

Comment: I updated the list of methods. There are couple more now.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you for taking the time to document this.

Answer (score 5):

Things have changed now with version 0.20.0. The methods `getTypeScriptWorker` and `getJavaScriptWorker` return a valid type now:

```
    export const getTypeScriptWorker: () => Promise<(...uris: Uri[]) => Promise<TypeScriptWorker>>;
    export const getJavaScriptWorker: () => Promise<(...uris: Uri[]) => Promise<TypeScriptWorker>>;
```

Also the promise parameter has changed.

With this change it is no longer necessary to maintain an own worker (proxy) type.

Answer (score 3):

The discussion so far focused on getting the JS/TS worker proxy, but there's a much easier solution for the original question about how to get transpiled code:

```js
    import ts from "typescript";

    this.worker.postMessage({ code: ts.transpile(context.code) });
```

This is how I send TS code from the editor to a web worker for isolated execution.

Comment: Is the difference, perhaps, that your variant runs the transpilation on the main thread, while the other answers offload it to a worker?

Comment: I'm not sure which difference you mean and btw. I recommend not to access Monaco in a worker thread, at least not when you use a bundler like webpack or rollup, because it will include the entire Monaco code into that worker bundle, which makes this huge (> 4MB).